# JQuery AJAX problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

If you look at http://www.danfarrellwright.com/screwsline/front_end/product.php?product_id=104
I have written the following function to add the table headers in every five rows:

```
jQuery.fn.hrReplace = function() {
    var headers = $(this).find('table.products tr:eq(0)');

    $(this).find('table.products tr:nth-child(5n)').after(headers);
    $(this).find('table.products tr:eq(0)').before(headers);
}
```

This works fine on loading the page.  I have then added the function during the ajax command:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: formAction,
    data: myForm,
    success: function() {
        $('#top_bar').load(base + 'index.php #top_bar');
        $('#' + divId).load(document.URL + '&amp;random=' + Math.random() * 99999 + ' #' + divId, {
            'gaugeMinFil':parseFloat($('input[name="gaugeLow"]').val()),
            'gaugeMaxFil':parseFloat($('input[name="gaugeHigh"]').val()),
            'lengthMinFil':parseFloat($('input[name="lengthLow"]').val()),
            'lengthMaxFil':parseFloat($('input[name="lengthHigh"]').val())
        });
        $('#tableHolder').hrReplace();
    }
});
```

But after reloading the div hrReplace() isn't working.

Comment: What is the question? Also, please provide more details in the place of "isn't working"

Comment: Sorry, the hrReplace function takes the header row from the table and inserted it every fifth line in the table.  After completing an AJAX reload of the table the function no longer inserts the header row on every fifth line.

Comment: Where does the `headers` parameter come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call needs to be in the callback for the .load call, so it happens after it completes.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: formAction,
    data: myForm,
    success: function() {
        $('#top_bar').load(base + 'index.php #top_bar');
        $('#' + divId).load(document.URL + '&amp;random=' + Math.random() * 99999 + ' #' + divId, 
           {
            'gaugeMinFil':parseFloat($('input[name="gaugeLow"]').val()),
            'gaugeMaxFil':parseFloat($('input[name="gaugeHigh"]').val()),
            'lengthMinFil':parseFloat($('input[name="lengthLow"]').val()),
            'lengthMaxFil':parseFloat($('input[name="lengthHigh"]').val())
           }, 
           function() { 
               $('#tableHolder').hrReplace();
           }
        );
    }
});
```